# Why doesn't my loop display my JSON/API data onto my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch

I am creating an app for school where you can input a user name from GitHub and it will display that users Repos, in a list style. I have the code working where the `fetch()` is recieving the data, and the `.then()` is converting that response to JSON, but now im getting an error when i try to move that info into a loop wit jQuery to append it to my site.

Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

JS:

```
"use strict";

submitForm();

function submitForm(){
    $('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        getUserRepos();
    });
};

function getUserRepos(){
    var insertText = $('.inputBox').val();

    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${insertText}/repos`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response) 
            displayResults(response)
        });

};

function displayResults(response){
    $('#results-list').empty();

    for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
        $('#results-list').append(
            `<li>
            <a href="${response.url[i]}">
            <p>${response.name[i]}</p>
            </li>`
        )
    };

    $('#results').removeClass('hidden');
};
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>

        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Search GitHub User Repos</h1>
            <form>
                <label>Search Users</label>
                <input value="jacobtashley" class="inputBox" type="text" required>

                <input type="submit">
            </form>

            <section id="results" class="hidden">
                <h2>Search Results</h2>
                <ul id="results-list">    
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ypu are not closing the second <h3> .... <h3><p>${response.name[i]}</p>..... and as an aside - I would strongly advise against having a p inside a h3 - inside an li..... - yopu should choose the most approprite html element for isplaying the data and not try to make a p fint into a h - or in other owrds a pragraph fint into a heading inside a list item....

Comment: I removed those <h3>s from the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is issue with following line

```
<h3><a href="${response.url[i]}"></h3>
<h3><p>${response.name[i]}</p>
```

Try to change it to:

```
<h3><a href="${response[i].url}"></h3>
<h3><p>${response[i].name}</p>
```

Try this:

```js
submitForm();

function submitForm() {
    $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        getUserRepos();
    });
};

function getUserRepos() {
    var insertText = $('.inputBox').val();
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${insertText}/repos`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            //console.log(response)
            displayResults(response)
        });
};

function displayResults(response) {
    $('#results-list').empty();
    for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        $('#results-list').append(
            `<li>
<h3><a href="${response[i].url}"></h3>
<h3><p>${response[i].name}</p>
</li>`
        )
    };

    $('#results').removeClass('hidden');
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Search GitHub User Repos</h1>
    <form>
        <label>Search Users</label>
        <input value="jacobtashley" class="inputBox" type="text" required>

        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <section id="results" class="hidden">
        <h2>Search Results</h2>
        <ul id="results-list">
        </ul>
    </section>
</div>
```